# 'x' Converted to html code in example: 5x10

Tags: pages

I've created a page that includes a size such as 5x10 since the given term is something people often Google for, together with some other words.

Wordpress is converting 5x10 to: ***& # 2 1 5 ;***
(without the spaces)

Is there any way to prevent this?

I suppose that there are places where this feature would be useful but in my case it's hindering my SEO efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is performed by [`wptexturize()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize). Unfortunately it saves replacement lists as static variables which you can't modify.

So your options are:

1. Remove `wptexturize` filter from related hook (depends on where you have that replacement done).
2. Write and add your own filter that will replace converted symbol back.

Comment: 3. wrap the x between spaces